# Rails 3 - Validating against virtual attribute results in Exception

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, number-formatting, virtual-attribute

I have a virtual attribute, called currentBalance, in one of my models. An ajax call in my view populates this attribute. In the model I'm trying to validate that the net_weight is less than or equal to the currentBalance which represents total net weight for a product in inventory.

The problem is appears to be that net_weight is a float and the currentBalance attribute comes back as a string resulting in an exception that says:

> comparison of Float with String failed

Here is the jquery that populates the currentBalance input field when a product is selected:

```
$( ".fields" ).each( function(){    
    <% @currentBals.each do |c| %>
        if( $(this).find("option:selected").text() == '<%= c.material %>' ) {   
            $(this).find("input:text[readonly]").val("<%= number_with_delimiter(c.currentBal) %>")  
        } else {
            if ($(this).find("option:selected").text() == 'Select Material'){
                $(this).find("input:text[readonly]").val("<%=  number_with_delimiter(0) %>")
            }
        }
    <% end %>    

});
```

and here is the validation code in the model:

```
validates :net_weight, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0.0, less_than_or_equal_to: :currentBalance }
```

I think that the number_with_delimiter formatting statement is causing the problem. But I want the value to be formatted in the view.

How can I change the validation or convert the currentBalance attribute to be a float prior to the validation running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, although I think its a bit hacky. In my controllers' create action I looped through each detail record and parsed the comma out of currentBalance attribute and then called .to_f on it.

```
@shipment.details.each do |d|
         d.currentBalance = d.currentBalance.delete(',').to_f
end
```

I'd prefer to push this logic into the model but after multiple attempts (and in the interest of time) this approach worked. If anyone has an idea about how I can push the logic into the detail model and still make sure it validates correctly I'd be happy to try it.

Answer (score 0):

The input tag for the current balance is of type text. Try changing that tag to type

number(`type="number")` and for floating number add a step attribute(e.g `step="0.01"`) and change the

```
$(this).find("input:text[readonly]")
```

to

```
$(this).find("input:number[readonly]")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This approach netted the same result after I change the .js and view files to use number inputs.